# dynamic programming solution on path finding with maximum sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem is I have a 2 * n array filled by numbers. I want to start from (0,0) cell and move right, up, or down to reach the (1,n) cell. Every cell should be visited at most once and the sum of numbers in the path should be maximum. for example, if I have this array:

```
1 2 5
-1 3 4
```

the moves should be down, right, up, right, down. So the maximum sum is 1 + (-1) + 3 + 2 + 5 + 4 = 14

I tried to solve the problem using dynamic programming by finding the maximum elemnts for each column but that didn't work. My solution was something like this:

```
dp[0][0] = arr[0][0];
dp[1][0] = arr[1][0] + arr[0][0];
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    // here we predict 4 numbers and find the maximum one
    // so we can get maximum score on each column
    int predicta1 = arr[1][i] + dp[1][i - 1]; // predict for 1,i (down)
    int predicta2 = predicta1 + arr[0][i];    // predict for 0,i (up)

    int predictb1 = arr[1][i] + arr[0][i] + dp[0][i - 1]; // predict for 1,i (down)
    int predictb2 = arr[0][i] + dp[0][i - 1]; // predict for 0,i (up)
    int maximum = max(predicta1, max(predicta2, max(predictb1, predictb2)));
}
```

Can anyone help how to solve this problem using DP or any other approach?

Comment: Every cell should be visited once?  Addition is commutative, so all paths visiting every cell once will result in the same sum.  What am I not getting?

Comment: Also, if left is not allowed, I can't think of *any other path* to all nodes besides down-right-up-right- etc. If left is allowed, I can't see how to use left without violating the "only once" constraint.  Are you sure you've stated the problem correctly?

Comment: I mean at most once. sorry for that. and left is not allowed because of that visiting limit. If you go left you can't reach the (1,n) without visiting a cell at least twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not far from the solution.
The idea is to use the fact that we cannot go to the left.

We iteratively calculate the maximums at position `[0][i]` and `[1][i]`. For example:

```
Max at [1][i] = max (Max at [1][i-1] + A[1][i], Max at [0][i-1] + A[0][i] + A[1][i]);
```

Etc.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int path2 (std::vector<std::vector<int>>& A) {
    int n = A[0].size();
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    int predit0 = A[0][0];
    int predit1 = A[0][0] + A[1][0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int sum = A[0][i] + A[1][i];
        int temp = std::max (predit0 + A[0][i], predit1 + sum);
        predit1 = std::max (predit1 + A[1][i], predit0 + sum);
        predit0 = temp;
    }
    return predit1;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> A = {
        {1, 2, 5},
        {-1, 3, 4}
    };
    auto ans = path2(A);
    std::cout << "max sum = " << ans << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```